# Pageable request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, resttemplate

I have two microservices written in Java 17 and Spring Boot 3. One is using Spring Data for connection with the database and have a controller that returns the Page<MyOwnType>. The other one, doesnt have spring data dependency and is supposed to make a request to the first one and obtain the results of the MyOwnType and if there are still more results, it should repeat the request.

I am using restTemplate for it. How can I get the Page type in my microservice without the spring data dependency? I believe it is a common way to request for the pageable data.

```
ResponseEntity<Page<MyOwnType>> response = restTemplate.exchange(myurl, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Page<MyOwnType>>() {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create your own Page class that mimics the structure of the Page class from Spring Data, so that you can deserialize the JSON response from your first microservice into your own Page class.

Ex:

```
public class MyOwnPage<T> {
private List<T> content;
private int pageNumber;
private int pageSize;
private long totalElements;

// getters and setters
```

}

Then, you can use it in the RestTemplate in your second microservice without depending on Spring Data.

```
ResponseEntity<MyOwnPage<MyOwnType>> response = ...
```

Comment: I think that's the best way, but I am still kind of shocked that it wasn't already handled, cause it is a very common approach...